# "Безопасная" CMS для госучреждений

Tags: cms, безопасность

Думаю, все в курсе, что ФЗ №152 - это теперь жесткое требование для госучреждений. Как быть, если требуется создать внутри сети портал, который должен удовлетворять данному закону? Вариант первый - писать вручную с учетом всех нюансов. Вариант второй - использовать готовое. Может уже есть такие CMS?

Comment: Вы б хотя бы в двух словах описали, что требует закон... Вряд ли кто-то ответит без приставки IANAL.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос неверно поставлен. Любая CMS может быть самой защищенной в руках грамотного админа. Даже в хвалёном "Битриксе" куча дыр, хотя казалось бы... Нужно не "безопасную" CMS искать, а хорошего админа. Не иначе.

CMS выбирают из расчёта на необходимую функциональность, безопасную искать бесполезно - все дырявые по сути.

**Обновление**

Я держусь подальше от "госучреждений" (насколько возможно, конечно), поэтому про то, что требует закон, я понятия не имею. Даже после его прочтения.

Но ответ тот же - грамотный админ в любую CMS настроить в соответствии с законом.

Правда я думаю что для государства нужно бы нанять команду для создания системы, которая удовлетворяет все потребности заказчика и закона. Уж на страну скупиться нельзя, ох нельзя...

Comment: Вы, вероятно, не поняли вопроса. Имеется в виду специфика требований указанного закона. А не безопасноcть самой CMS

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум у 1С есть сертифицированный ФСТЭКом Внутренний портал государственной организации на Битрикс.